# Data arrangement in CSV file

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, csv, land-classification, soilgrids

I am getting whole data in a row while exporting CSV file . I need data in separate columns in CSV file. Soil variable value in a separate column and pixel counts against each soil variable in next column.

Here is my code:

```
Map.addLayer(Chenab);

var roi = ee.FeatureCollection(Chenab).geometry();
Map.centerObject(roi, 10);

var startDate = '2021-05-28';

var endDate = '2022-07-01';

var soil_class = ee.Image("OpenLandMap/SOL/SOL_TEXTURE-CLASS_USDA-TT_M/v02")
              .select('b0').clip(roi)
              .rename('soil');

// Converting soil textute into soil group
// A == 1, B == 2,  C == 3, D == 4

var soil_grp = soil_class.expression(

    "(b('soil') > 10) ? 4" +

      ": (b('soil') > 4) ? 3" +

        ": (b('soil') > 1) ? 2" +

           ": (b('soil') > 0) ? 1" +

             ": 0"

).rename('soil');

var dw = ee.ImageCollection('GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1')
             .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
             .filterBounds(roi);

// Create a mode composite.

var classification = dw.select('label');

var dwComposite = classification.reduce(ee.Reducer.mode());

var mask = dwComposite;

var masked_image = dwComposite.updateMask(mask);

var dwVisParams = {
  min: 0,
  max: 8,
  palette: [
    '#419BDF', '#397D49', '#88B053', '#7A87C6', '#E49635', '#DFC35A',
    '#C4281B', '#A59B8F', '#B39FE1'
  ]
};

// Clip the composite and add it to the Map.

Map.addLayer(masked_image.clip(roi), dwVisParams, 'Classified Composite');


var dwComposite = masked_image.rename(['classification']);


// Combined LULC & SOil in single image

var lulc_soil = dwComposite.addBands(soil_grp)
Map.addLayer (lulc_soil, {}, 'Soil & LULC', 0)

 
var pixelCountStats = dwComposite.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram().unweighted(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: 10,
    maxPixels: 1e10
    });

var pixelCounts = ee.Dictionary(pixelCountStats.get('classification'));
print(pixelCounts);


// Format the results to make it more readable.

var classLabels = ee.List([
    'water', 'trees', 'grass', 'flooded_vegetation', 'crops',
    'shrub_and_scrub', 'built', 'bare', 'snow_and_ice'
    ]);

// Rename keys with class names.

var pixelCountsFormatted = pixelCounts.rename(
  pixelCounts.keys(), classLabels);

var lulc_soil2 = (soil_grp.multiply(100)).add(dwComposite)
Map.addLayer (lulc_soil2, {}, "lulc_soil2")
var pixelCountStats2 = lulc_soil2.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram().unweighted(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: 10,
    maxPixels: 1e10
    });
 
   print(pixelCountStats2);  
 
  
var exportFc2 = ee.FeatureCollection(
  ee.Feature(null, pixelCountStats2));


// Export the results as a CSV file.

Export.table.toDrive({

  collection: exportFc2,

  description: 'pixel_counts_export',

  folder: 'earthengine',

  fileNamePrefix: 'pixel_counts',

  fileFormat: 'CSV',

});
```

That's how I am getting data:

```
system:index,soil,.geo
0,"{null=7.4860641E7, 301=7.0365657E7, 206=1515830.0, 202=221592.0, 4=20322.0, 8=8889896.0, 305=3.6723618E7, 306=5188640.....
```

That's what I want in CSV file:

```
system:index, soil

0, null,7.486064E7

1,301,7.0365657E7

2,206,1515830.0
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Kindly describe your problem rather just providing the code.

Comment: I am getting whole data in a row while exporting CSV file . I need data in separate columns in CSV file. soil variable value in a separate column and pixel counts against each soil variable in next column. I described the way how data is presented in CSV file at the end of above post, and how i want it to display.

Comment: Please [Edit] your Question in response to requests for clarification. Comments are intended to be *ephemeral*, not a core part of the Question content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pixelCountStats2` is a dictionary with key soil and value of in a list which is also a nested dictionary. When a feature collection from this dictionary is created, there is only one feature.

[image]

To create a multiple features from this dictionary, it needs to be broken down into several data structures. Firstly, the values of the dictionary is extracted and a new dictionary is created. The values are actually as a list, so the first element from the list is drawn out using the `get(0)`. Next, the keys are stored in a variable and it is mapped such that each key turns into a new feature and the properties are assigned accordingly.

```js
var data=ee.Dictionary(pixelCountStats2.values().get(0))
var keys=data.keys()

var exportFc2 = ee.FeatureCollection(
  keys.map(function(k){
    return ee.Feature(null,{'Soil':k,'Pixel':data.get(k)})}));
```